Why is f and s orbital considered valence orbitals
When I look at energy diagrams, it shows that 6s has lower energy than 4f orbital which has lower energy than 5d orbital.
Why do a lot of sources say 6s has highest energy and that lanthanides donate from valence orbital (6s orbital), when in reality they are donating from inner orbital and 5d has the highest energy.
5d should be considered valence orbital, then.
I know in transition metals d orbital is valence orbital as it has highest energy but transition metals first donate electrons from s orbitals which are inner orbitals.
Overall I want to know why some people are labelling orbitals that aren't valence as valence?

When considering a heavy atom the energy associated to the orbitals with different quantum numbers n and l does not follow the order of the hydrogen orbitals. You have to take into account the interaction of the electrons in that orbital with the rest of the electrons, besides for the lanthanides the relativistic interactions are also important.

These electron in this orbitals are called valence electrons because you have to use this orbitals  when describing the bonding of this atoms. They do not behave as inner or core electrons.

According to the Aufbau principle, electrons must be added to the lowest energy subshell first. Thus, when writing the electronic configuration of elements, we follow the Aufbau principle. According to this principle, the 6s subshell is filled first, followed by the 4f subshell, and then the 5d subshell. This principle is applied when adding electrons to an atom.
However, when an electron is lost (ionization), the Aufbau principle is not followed. Instead, we consider the outermost subshell, which is the one with the highest principal quantum number (n) and then highest azimuthal quantum number (l) of that shell. For lanthanides, the 6s subshell is the outermost subshell (n=6, l=0). Therefore, when a lanthanide element loses an electron, it is taken from the 6s subshell.
The valence subshell is the subshell involved in chemical bonding. For s- and p-block elements, their outermost subshells are their valence subshells. However, for d- and f-block elements, when they are donating electrons, their outermost subshell becomes the valence subshell. When accepting electrons, the d or f subshells are considered as the valence subshells.

Thank you this is very informative and useful. I was just wondering isn't the outermost shell of f-block elements 5d subshell as it has highest energy. So shouldn't that be considered valence shell

The electronic configuration of cerium (an f-block element) is [Xe] 4f¹ 5d¹ 6s². In this configuration, 6s² is the outermost subshell (n=6, l=0). Therefore, 6s is the outermost subshell for f-block elements. If cerium donates an electron, then 6s will be considered its valence subshell. However, if it accepts an electron, 4f will become its valence subshell.
